# How to safely combine script-src with known JSONP endpoint hosters like syndication.twimg.com?

Tags: jsonp, content-security-policy

I'm playing with Content Security Policy for a page with embedded tweets and I'm getting reports for `https:/​/​cdn.syndication.twimg.com`, which isn't allowed in my policy.

It's a pretty long policy but the relevant parts are

```
default-src 'none'; ... script-src 'self' apis.google.com platform.twitter.com; ...
```

However, if I add `cdn.syndication.twimg.com` or `*.twimg.com` to the `script-src` part of the header, I get a warning when I run the header through the [Google CSP evaluator](https://csp-evaluator.withgoogle.com/):

> `cdn.syndication.twimg.com` is known to host JSONP endpoints which allow to bypass this CSP.

Some other domains also provoke this warning.

It seems that I'm between a rock and a hard place: either I disallow Twitter from running scripts (needed? I really don't know) and get policy violation reports, or I'm running with a pretty much useless CSP.

Is there a way out of this conundrum?

Answer (score 1):

The validator does not complain if you change `script-src` to `script-src-elem`.

I suspect this is a bug in the validator rather than a fix to the reported vulnerability. Open JSONP endpoints are equally exploitable with either CSP stanza.

Comment: thanks, but that one is unsupported in most browsers at this moment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Security-Policy/script-src-elem